# As3 splitting my array's first position

Tags: xml, arrays, actionscript-3

Okay I have a problem I have never faced before, and I don't really understand how it come to be but I need some advice.

I have several elements in my XML that looks like this:

```
<Pictures>
<Url>http://images.bilinfo.dk/images/44700028.jpg</Url>
<Url>http://images.bilinfo.dk/images/44700028_1.jpg</Url>
<Url>http://images.bilinfo.dk/images/44700028_2.jpg</Url>
<Url>http://images.bilinfo.dk/images/44700028_3.jpg</Url>
<Url>http://images.bilinfo.dk/images/44700028_4.jpg</Url>
<Url>http://images.bilinfo.dk/images/44700028_5.jpg</Url>
<Url>http://images.bilinfo.dk/images/44700028_6.jpg</Url>
<Url>http://images.bilinfo.dk/images/44700028_7.jpg</Url>
<Url>http://images.bilinfo.dk/images/44700028_8.jpg</Url>
<Url>http://images.bilinfo.dk/images/44700028_9.jpg</Url>
<Url>http://images.bilinfo.dk/images/44700028_10.jpg</Url>
<Url>http://images.bilinfo.dk/images/44700028_11.jpg</Url>
</Pictures>
```

As you can see this is only one element with alot of children. BUT when I have made a code to look for every Picture element and put them in an array I have this code:

```
var testCheck:int = imgData.Vehicle.Pictures.length();
trace(testCheck);
var D:Array = [];
    if(C.indexOf("44700008") < 0)
    {
        for ( var l: int = 0; l < testCheck; l++)
        {

             D[l] = [imgData.Vehicle.Pictures[l]];
            //trace(D);
        }
```

Now the problem is if I try to do a trace(D[0]); I will recieve 5 different URLS (Which is correct) BUT how do I divide these four URLs Into another Array with 4 elements?

I know it might be hard to understand what I want, that's cause I'm having a bit of a problem describing it myself :/

But this code maybe describes it better: 
     if (D[0])
            {
                var imageLength:int = D[0].length;
                trace(imageLength);

```
            for (var i: int = 0; i < 4 ; i++)
            {

                raw_image = imgData.Vehicle.Pictures.Url[i];
                imageLoader = new UILoader;
                var context:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext();
                context.applicationDomain = ApplicationDomain.currentDomain;
                imageLoader.width = 250;
                imageLoader.height = 250;
                imageLoader.load(new URLRequest(raw_image), context);
                A[i].addChild(imageLoader);
            }
        }
```

As you can see I'm trying to take all the URL's in the D[0] and put them into different UILoaders I have on my stage. but now D[0] is one element containing four URLS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object in D[0] is probably an XMLList. You can access each element in an XMLList like this:

```
public function showList(list:XMLList):void {
    var item:XML;
    for each(item in list) {
        trace("item: " + item.toXMLString());
        // you could .push the current item into a _urls Array here...
    }
}
```